# Necessary to change chemical leavener for sugar substitution in baking recipe?

Tags: substitutions, sugar, acidity, baking-soda

If I substitute raw sugar for white sugar, do I need to add more baking soda/less powder to offset any additional acidity raw sugar may contain?

Answer (score 1):

in most baking recipes, the additional acidity from raw sugar or brown sugar being used instead of white sugar is in the noise in terms of leavening.  You should not need to make any adjustments for leavening.

On the other hand, they may be more hydroscopic, and so the item may tend to be moister.